# I want to add several elements to a widget in python and it crashes

Tags: python, gtk

I'm creating a jukebox-like software with python, and need to add N elements to a GtkListBox element.

it crashes and i get: `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"`

this is the code

```
for item in self.album_data:
        self.contenedor_album.add(Gtk.Label(label=item))
```

Answer (score 0):

It was libraries program, i had to reinstall python and all modules again

if you have same problem try uninstall and install python and all modules again